# Looping over a JSON object, not getting the results I'm expecting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an AJAX request like this:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: accessURL,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                 $.each(data.results, function (i, val) {
                    //console.log(data);
                    marketId.push(val.id);
                    marketName.push(val.marketname);
                 });

                console.log(marketName);
                console.log(marketId);
```

The returned data ('console.log(data)') contains:

```
Object {results: Array[19]}
    results: Array[19]
        0: Object
            id: "1003777"
            marketname: "2.1 El Dorado Hills, Thursday Farmers Market"
        1: Object
        2: Object
        3: Object
        //... etc. each object has an id and marketname
```

The problem is with `console.log(marketName);` it's returning the wrong marketName.

I know this is probably as clear as mud, so if you need to see the entire script, please feel free to take a look on [GitHub](https://github.com/pauldessert/SeedTip/blob/master/js/map.js). You can also see a functional example at [www.seedtip.com](http://www.seedtip.com) Or ask for clarification.

Comment: where is marketId and marketNametting declared.if its just plain variables push wont work. push works only for arrays.

Comment: I hate to send you to a wall of code, but in this situation it might be the best option https://github.com/pauldessert/SeedTip/blob/master/js/map.js

Comment: When I see the data returned, there is no array on the `results` object. The json returned is like this: `{"marketdetails":{"Address":"....","GoogleLink":...`

Comment: BTW: "... `console.log(marketName);` it's returning the wrong marketName. ...": It won't show *wrong* marketName, it will show you the entire array in the console.

Comment: What are you expecting to see?  Tell us what value you searched with (e.g., what ZIP, etc.)

Comment: @ps2goat - enter any zip code. You'll get a working result set. Look at the titles on the map markers. Refresh the page, renter the zip and look again. The titles will randomly switch. Might might take 3 or 4 times, ut you should notice some of the marker titles switching

Comment: Your logic has to be change, dont use counter

Comment: The first issue I see is that every time I submit a zip code, you are just adding more data to the existing arrays.  you need to set them back to empty, e.g., `marketId = []; marketName = []; $.each(data.results, function (i, val) {      //console.log(data);      marketId.push(val.id);      marketName.push(val.marketname);      });`

Comment: @ps2goat very true, thanks. However, upon a page refresh they'll be reset. So, I don't think that's affecting this issue

Comment: It looks like your main issue is that you believe the data coming back from the second ajax call will be in the same order as the data from the first call.  You'll have to change the way you're trying to get the data.

Comment: @ps2goat - Thanks! You're right. It looks like it was switching the order. I changed the way I'm pulling the data and it seems to work now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a copy of your array before passing it to console.log();

I had a similar issue once and found out that console.log() is deferring the actual output some time (probably also depends on the browser). It stores a reference to your array but prints it a bit later. If you are passing a string, this is not a problem, but it is for reference types. You are probably seeing the effect of later changes in the output of console.log.

Comment: Thanks, but it was actually an issue with the way the API was returning the data